# How to supply a default value iff a value is None?

Tags: python, functional-programming, option-type

Is there an operator or a library function such that `v ??? d`

- evaluates to `v` if `v` is distinct from `None` and doesn't evaluate `d`, or
- evaluates to `d` if `v` is equal to `None`.

(where by `???` I denote the operator I'm seeking).

Operator `or` is almost what I want, but it evaluates to the default value if `v` is `False`. I want the default only if the argument is `None`, so that `False ??? d` evaluates to `False`.

---

**Update:** To clarify, in my case `v` can be a complex expression, like `computeSomethingLong() ??? d`. So I can't use

```
computeSomethingLong() if computeSomethingLong() is not None else d
```

I'd have to do something like

```
tempvar = computeSomethingLong()
tempvar if tempvar is not None else d
```

which feels quite awkward, compared to `computeSomethingLong() or d`.

---

**Update:** The closest I got is to define my own function:

```
def orElse(v, deflt):
    if v is not None:
        v
    else:
        deflt
```

But the drawback is that `deflt` is always evaluated! I want it to evaluate *only* if it's actually needed. In particular, I want that in

```
firstLongComputation() ??? secondLongComputation()
```

the first computation is evaluated; if it's result is not `None`, it is returned. Otherwise the second one is evalauted (and only in this case) and it will be the result of the expression.

Comment: and what do you want to do if v=d? This case is not contemplated, right?

Comment: @Jblasco It doesn't really matter. I want `d` to be only evaluated if `v` is `None`, so we can't compare the values to decide anything.

Comment: Sorry, but it DOES matter. If you want v=d if and only if v=None, you need to give v another value if, from the beginning, v=d. Only if v will never be d from the beginning this discussion does not matter.

Comment: @Jblasco I believe this is a misunderstanding. I don't want to modify `v` at all, nor compare it to `d`. I only want to compare `v` to `None`, and act accordingly. I'll update the question.

Comment: Jeje, ok. I'll try to make myself clear. If you get d at the exit of your program, will you conclude that v was None? Because you might be wrong. If v=d from the beginning, it was NOT None, so you take v, which is equal to d as your result, and at the exit you get d. Are you happy with that?

Comment: Can `v` be 0, an empty string, False? And if so, do you want it to yield 0, empty string, or False, instead of `v`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I want to preserve the value of `v` if it is anything but `None`.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such operator, but it's straigtforward anyway using ternary if "operator"

```
v if v is not None else d
```

If `v` is an expensive function call, you can employ any kind of [caching (aka memoization)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578231-probably-the-fastest-memoization-decorator-in-the-/) to still use the same approach:

```
@memoize
def computeSomethingLong():
   """whatever"""

computeSomethingLong() if computeSomethingLong() else computeSomethingElse()
```

Will still evaluate `computeSomethingLong` **once**.

See [python manual](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) or [some other instructions](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) for details on decorators.

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest idea so far. The problem with it is if `computeSomethingLong` has a (desired) side effect. For example, if it reads and parses a value from a network socket.

Comment: Than you've got some reason to rework the program flow to either (1) remove side effects from the function or (2) explicitly call it once. Anyway, you are trying to do something quite quirky :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `v if v is not None else d`